# jquery clone a link (once per div)

Tags: javascript, jquery, clone

I have a set of divs, and need to clone the link from the top and insert into the last div (mobile-link). It is either cloning the links from all of the divs, and then inserting all of them at once, or if I use :eq(0), it's putting the first link into all of the divs.

```
<div class="course"><a href="/accounting">Accounting</a></div>
<div class="start-date">1-1-2017</div>
<div class="credits">4</div>
<div class="location">Online</div>
<div class="mobile-link"></div>

<div class="course"><a href="/business">Business</a></div>
<div class="start-date">1-1-2017</div>
<div class="credits">3</div>
<div class="location">Online/Campus</div>
<div class="mobile-link"></div>

<script>
    $(".course a:eq(0)").clone().appendTo(".mobile-link");        
</script>
```

What do I need to change to make this work properly?

Answer (score 2):

You need to process each anchor separately:

```
$(".course").each(function() {
    var myLink = $(this).find('a').clone();
    $(this).nextAll('.mobile-link').first().append(myLink);
});
```

**[Demo fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k56fqks9/2)**

Comment: Think you should go with `nextAll('.mobile-link').first()` instead.

Comment: Thank you, @skobaljic. You were right. I've updated the demo.

Answer (score 1):

**[Append](http://api.jquery.com/append/)** method can take a **function** as **argument**, and here it is *appending* to the each `.mobile-link` first `<a>` from his previous `.course div`

```
$(".mobile-link").append(function(){
  return $(this).prevAll('.course:first').find('a:first').clone(); 
});
```

Check the **below snippet**

```js
$(".mobile-link").append(function(i) {
  return $(this).prevAll('.course:first').find('a:first').clone();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="course"><a href="/accounting">Accounting</a>
</div>
<div class="start-date">1-1-2017</div>
<div class="credits">4</div>
<div class="location">Online</div>
<div class="mobile-link"></div>

<div class="course"><a href="/business">Business</a>
</div>
<div class="start-date">1-1-2017</div>
<div class="credits">3</div>
<div class="location">Online/Campus</div>
<div class="mobile-link"></div>
```

Comment: this worked perfect. Thanks a lot for the quick response!

Answer (score 0):

I beleive that you should use last (If I understood question correctly):

```
var lastDiv = $(".mobile-link").last();
$(".course a:eq(0)").clone().appendTo(lastDiv);
```

Here is jsfiddle: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/NemanjaT/3075ax10/)